# Password Protecting Content in Public with Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

```
Rails 5.1.4
Puma 3.11.0
```

Moving the content to a controller and password-protecting that is not a good option because the content has a lot of internal links that would break in that context.

Production environment is Heroku.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Puma doesn't support `.htaccess` file because it is not Apache HTTP server. If you really want to use password when you access to file, you can use `http_basic_authenticate_with`.

You will add to your top of controller. When you Google it, you will find more about this function.

Thank you.

Comment: I said in my question that using a controller (which I know how to password protect) is not a good option.

Comment: exactly what they said they didn't want to do. In the same boat, did you ever find an answer? Need to secure the public directory (static API documents)